# transfer ether from smart contract wallet to normal wallet

Tags: ether, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, internal-transactions

I have transferred ether from smart contract wallet (Throughbit exchange) to normal ether wallet (Koinex exchange). The transaction in block chain is confirmed but koinex told me they have not received the ether. Have my ether gone. Is there any way to retrieve those ether. https://etherscan.io/address/0x30d602125779e67ee783eaf7560f8b137172ded1

Comment: Was the transferred ETHER reflected on your Koinex account please ?
if so, can you throw some light on it. I did a similar transfer and etherscan.io showed the transaction as success with my ETH address containing the transferred ETHER value, but it is not loaded in "Koinex" ETH account after ~2 days. -Bala R

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14877)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ether have arrived to that address. Make sure that it is the correct address that you were supposed to send it to

If it is, and they still will not credit you the ether, then you are being scammed.

If it is not, then you made a very costly mistake and will not get that ether back.

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its the correct address. What should I do now

Comment: Contact that exchange again. Besides that, there is nothing you can really do. Lot of scams these days